# How to join 3 patterns as a line with awk

Tags: shell, awk, gawk

Im got text similar to this one in a file.

```
OVM>
show PhysicalDisk id='12346579123456789123456789'
Data:
  Page83 ID = OVM_SYS_REPO_PART_12346579123456789123456789
  Server Reserved = No
  Shareable = No
  Size (GiB) = 503.37
  State = UNKNOWN
  Thin Provision = No
  Type = LUN
  User-Friendly Name = 200173800eeec23ff
  Vendor = Lenovo
  File System 1 = 12346579123456789123456789
  Volume Group = 12346579123456789123456789  [Local Storage Volume Group]
  Id = 12346579123456789123456789 [OVM_SYS_REPO_PART_12346579123456789123456789]
  Name = OVM_SYS_REPO_PART_12346579123456789123456789
  Locked = false
OVM>
show PhysicalDisk id='123465791234567891234567892'
Data:
  Storage Targets 1 = 0x50017380eeec0140
  Storage Targets 2 = 0x50017380eeec0170
  Storage Targets 3 = 0x50017380eeec0150
  Storage Targets 4 = 0x50017380eeec0172
  Storage Targets 5 = 0x50017380eeec0152
  Storage Targets 6 = 0x50017380eeec0182
  Page83 ID = 200173800eeec23aa
  Server Reserved = No
  Shareable = Yes
  Size (GiB) = 16.03
  State = UNKNOWN
  Thin Provision = Yes
  Type = LUN
  User-Friendly Name = 200173800eeec23aa
  Vendor = IBM
  File System 1 = 123465791234567891234567892  [Server Pool File System]
  Volume Group = 123465791234567891234567892  [FibreChannel Volume Group]
  Id = 123465791234567891234567892  [Production Quorum LUN]
  Name = Production LUN
  Locked = false
OVM>
```

I want to pick only the "User-Friendly Name", "Size" and "Name" lines for each output (for each "show") and join them like so.

> User-Friendly Name = 200173800eeec23aa  Name = Production LUN Size (GiB) = 16.03

In fact, it would be even better if I could get:

> 200173800eeec23aa Production LUN 16.03

I tried this but for some reason it sticks a \n between each line instead at the end of the 3 patterns:

```
awk 'match($0, /(User.*)|(Name.*)|(Size.*)/, a) {printf "%s %s %s\n", a[1], a[2], a[3]}' object_data/LUNs.txt
```

So I'm actually getting (including that weird identation):

```
User-Friendly Name = 200173800eeec23aa
 Name = Production LUN
  Size (GiB) = 16.03
```

How can I fix this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an awk script for your situation:

**script.awk:**

```
BEGIN {FS="="}
$1 ~ "User-Friendly Name" { ufn = $2 }
$1 ~ "Size" { sz = $2 }
$1 ~ "Name" { printf("%s%s%s\n",ufn,$2, sz) }
```

Use it like `awk -f script.awk yourfile`.

Explanation for your output: Each line is matched for **itself**. 
For example the line containing Size is matched by the second parenthesis from your original awk script. 
The line contains only "Size (GiB)...": so:

- `a[1]` and `a[3]` are empty
- `a[2]` is *the whole line* (due to the `.*`)
- the newline is the `\n` from the `printf`

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic awk approach:

```
$ awk -F' = ' '
   { gsub(/^ +| +\([^)]+\)$/,"",$1); m[$1]=$2 }
   NR>1 && /^OVM/{ print m["User-Friendly Name"], m["Name"], m["Size"] }
' file
200173800eeec23ff OVM_SYS_REPO_PART_12346579123456789123456789 503.37
200173800eeec23aa Production LUN 16.03
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove '\n' at the end of each line: gsub(/[\n]$/, "", $0)

Comment: You really should have tried that, it's wrong on so many levels.